# Is there any keyboard shortcut to send an email in iOS 9.2?

Tags: ios, keyboard, shortcut

I have an iPad mini with iOS 9.2 and a physical keyboard. The keyboard allows me to use several shortcuts when using some apps (for instance I can use Cmd+T to open a new tab in Safari or close it with Cmd+W).

I was wondering if there is any shorcut to send an email from the default app using a keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test this myself, as I do not have a Bluetooth keyboard, but I've seen a few article stating that to send an email you could type **CMD - Shift - D**.